# PHP Design Pattern for checking if a class should be executed

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I've developed a Laravel-based app that sends out various emails such as informing users of new jobs as well as new messages.

I have created all the necessary Mail classes. We now want to create a database column that will allow individual users to set whether they want to receive those notification emails or not.

When a user performs an action that would normally send out an email, I want the system to check if the user wants to receive those emails based on their settings in the database. I don't want to wrap all calls to email, in the code, with unnecessary `if()` functions.

Is there a preferred design pattern that I could use to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you use laravel notifications?

Comment: how will that solve my problem?

Comment: how do you know what users are you sending those emails and notifications ?

Comment: @Vidal It's the email address inside Mail::to()

Comment: yes but how do you get those emails address on laravel? what I am trying to tell you is to update your query.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. The email address is stored on the user model in the db. @Vidal

Comment: $emails = Model::where('getEmails','=',1)->get();

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Facade Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

- Extend Laraval's `PendingMail` object
- Override the `send()` function to Only call `parent::send()` if your `if()` condition is met
- Make `Mail::to()` return your extended version

Laravel has some documentation on how to do this here:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail